# Getting selenium to launch safari with default profile in python

Tags: python, selenium, safari, webdriver

I'm trying to launch Safari with Selenium in python with all my sessions logged in (e.g. gmail) so I don't have to login manually.

The easy solution would be to launch safari with the default user profile, but I can't find documentation on how to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'https://www.gmail.com/'
driver.get(url)
```

Just for reference, the code below is the code for Chrome. What is the safari equivalent?

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/alexiseggermont/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you found? Did you look at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.safari.webdriver?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, Safari does not have user profiles. If you mean to start Safari from a different Mac user I would suggest doing it with bash:

```
sudo -u username python open.py
```

where `username` is the username of the user and `open.py` is your python file.

Comment: Is there a way to open safari using selenium with the saved passwords or keychain? Now normally when we open Safari, it takes in the saved passwords from keychain but when using selenium it opens a different one.

Answer (score 1):

There is `setDataDir()` function in SafariOptions on safari driver v2.43.1 according to [document](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.43.1/source-code/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariOptions.java) as following however I couldn't find any document about how to use it and there is no information about last versions:

```
* @param dataDir A File object pointing to the Safari installation's data directory.
* If {@code null}, the default installation location for the current platform will be used.


  public void setDataDir(File dataDir) {
    this.dataDir = Optional.fromNullable(dataDir);
  }
```